# Payment information shows nothing in Magento one-page checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento version 1.9.1.0. I want to remove the shipping information and shipping method step from one page checkout page. For that I changed some code in core file like:

In `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage.php`

```
public function getSteps()
    {

        $steps = array();
        $stepCodes = $this->_getStepCodes();
        /* remove Shipping address and Shipping Method */
        $excludeStep=array_diff($stepCodes,array('shipping','shipping_method'));
        //$excludeStep=$stepCodes;
        if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $stepCodes = array_diff($excludeStep, array('login'));
        }
        foreach ($excludeStep as $step) {
            $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
        }
        return $steps;

    }
```

and in `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`

```
public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
//            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
//            $data = $this->_filterPostData($postData);
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
            /* Force full save Shpping Addredd */
            $resultShipp = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);
            $resultShipMethod = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()-> setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->save();
            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                /* check quote for virtual */
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                }
else

               {
                    /* force full set of shipping is free */
                        $shipping_method=array('shipping_method'=>'freeshipping_freeshipping');
                        $save_shippingmethod = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($shipping_method);          
                        if(!$save_shippingmethod)
                        {
                        $event =    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                                        array('request'=>$this->getRequest(),
                                            'quote'=>$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
                        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                        }
                        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
                        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shipping_method);
                        /* */
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                }
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
```

After implementing the above code, it is not showing shipping address and shipping method in process bar.But In payment information section, no payment method is coming. Before removing the steps, cash on delivery method was coming. But now there is no payment method available.

Comment: I guess it will be much easier just to change all your products' type to virtual product. Shipping Address and Shipping Method steps are automatically skipped by magento for virtual products.

Comment: can you please give me any other solution rather than this......

Comment: never attempt to change core classes of Magento. Override them instead. (p.s. I got the same problem, but no solution yet)